# How to reuse code by passing different type to ColumnPositionMappingStrategy for processing CSV

Tags: java, csv

I want to reuse the code below for different types. So for example I want use `ClassOne` to map values in the cvs file to `cls1field1` and `cls1field2` like the code below:

```
String[] columns = new String[] {"cls1field1", "cls1field2"};

ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<ClassOne> mappingStrategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<>();
mappingStrategy.setColumnMapping(columns);
mappingStrategy.setType(MyClassOne.class);

InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);

CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(in), ';');
CsvToBean<ClassOne> csv = new CsvToBean<>();
List<ClassOne> list = csv.parse(mappingStrategy, csvReader);
```

Now I want to do the same code for `ClassTwo` which has different fields, `cls2Field1` and `cls2Field2`.

The only solution I could think of is to substitute the `<ClassOne>` and `ClassOne.class` with `<Object>` and `Object.lass` and use casting if I want to access the members of list. I have tried to use an interface that both 'ClassOne' and `ClassTwo` implements but the problem is that the `cvs.parse` method uses `newInstance()` method to instantiate the classes.

What can I do to solve this problem properly?

Comment: Create a generic class called MappingStrategy<T> and encapsulate the code in this class.

Comment: @bot I don't know how your answer could solve the problem? Can you show me in an answer please?